# TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1. Use abi.encodePacked

Tags: solidity, abi, randomness

I was playing with [this post](https://www.sitepoint.com/solidity-pitfalls-random-number-generation-for-ethereum/) code example:

```
function random() private view returns (uint8) {
       return uint8(uint256(keccak256(block.timestamp, block.difficulty))%251);
   }
```

But I'm always getting this error:

```
TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1. This function requires a single bytes argument. Use abi.encodePacked
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance. I don't find too much info about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, you need to use `abi.encodePacked`:

```
function random() private view returns (uint8) {
    return uint8(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, block.difficulty)))%251);
}
```

More info about [ABI Encoding and Decoding Functions](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions).